# Using HealthKit with Fastlane Match

Tags: ios, healthkit, fastlane

I tried to enable the HealthKit capability in Xcode, but I got an error.

```
Add the HealthKit feature to your App ID.
Provisioning profile "match AdHoc com.mycompany.myapp" doesn't
support the HealthKit capability.
```

**Can I fix this? Do I have to ignore it?**

My Fastfile looks like that:

```
fastlane_version "2.35.1"

default_platform :ios

platform :ios do
  before_all do 
  end

  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    scan
  end

  desc "Build a new beta version"
  desc "This will also make sure the profile is up to date"
  lane :beta do

    register_devices(
      devices: {
        ...
      }
    )

    match(type: "adhoc", force_for_new_devices: true)

    gym(
      scheme: "myapp",
      clean: true,
      silent: true,
      output_directory: "../build/beta/"
    ) 
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the App Store"
  lane :release do
    match(type: "appstore")
    # snapshot
    gym(
      scheme: "myapp",
      clean: true,
      silent: true,
      output_directory: "../build/release/"
    ) 
  end
end
```

I also tried to nuke everything, but it didn't help.

Comment: Add more details to your question.. your fastlane script?? how you are calling it??

Comment: oh, I just added the capability via Xcode and got this error. Didn't do anything else. I use fastlane and match didn't change much from the default stuff the init command added. You think I could simply run a build and match would fix it?

Comment: I added my Fastfile if this helps.